# Script to merge a specific line of multiple .txt files into one .txt file

Tags: batch, script, merge

I have ~800 .txt files. I need extract the name of each file, and one line inside the file, and export it to a new .txt file.

The line I need to copy will always start with "System Boot Time:"

I'd like it to output inside the new .txt file something like this:

txtfile1

System Boot Time: xx/xx/xxxx

txtfile2

System Boot Time: xx/xx/xxxx

txtfile3

System Boot Time: xx/xx/xxxx

etc...

What commands can I use to do this?

Comment: In addition you haven't told us what operating system and scripting language you are using.

Comment: I am using windows 7 and writing a .bat script

Comment: `for /f`, `dir`, `findstr`, `echo` should get you started.

Comment: [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Comment: Thank you! It's difficult to know what to search for when you are very new to scripting. We know what we want in plain English but it's difficult to translate it to script-speak.

Comment: @davidpostill - Isn't this a bit harsh ?  (I can't answer it because I only do Linux, but this would be no more then 5 lines of code, and I routinely helped by providing scripts which are more complex on SU)

Comment: @davidgo I had some spare time this morning so I wrote an answer ...

Comment: @davidgo It's only a few lines of code but it's complicated (and needed tweaking to get it exactly right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I need extract the name of each file, and one line inside the file, and export it to a new .txt file.

> The line I need to copy will always start with `System Boot Time:`
>
> I'd like it to output inside the new .txt file something like this:

```
txtfile1
System Boot Time: xx/xx/xxxx
txtfile2
System Boot Time: xx/xx/xxxx
txtfile3
System Boot Time: xx/xx/xxxx
```

Use the following batch file.

**Merge.cmd:**

```
@echo off
setlocal 
for /f "useback delims=: tokens=1-3" %%i in (`findstr /C:"System Boot Time:" "*.txt"`) do (
  echo %%i >> new.txt
  echo %%j:%%k >> new.txt
)
endlocal
```

**Example output:**

```
F:\test>type ?.txt

1.txt


System Boot Time: 01/01/1900

2.txt


System Boot Time: 01/02/2003

3.txt


System Boot Time: 02/03/2004
    
F:\test>merge

F:\test>type new.txt
1.txt
System Boot Time: 01/01/1900
2.txt
System Boot Time: 01/02/2003
3.txt
System Boot Time: 02/03/2004
```

Notes:

- All files matching `*.txt` are searched for a string matching `System Boot Time
- Results are output to `new.txt`
- If you want to run `Merge.cmd` multiple times remember to `del new.txt` first.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.

Comment: Wow! That's great. Thank you so much - you've done a lot better than my pitiful attempts. One question - the new.txt file is returning every line that contains any of the words "System", "Boot" or "time". Is there a way I can make it match the entire string? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `sed` or even `grep` to output a line from a text file.

  (oh, I see you're on Windows. If you don't have `grep` or `sed` installed, you should be able to use `findstr` instead.)
- Put this command in a loop over the files needed.
- Redirect output to a file.